# how to style a multi-select drop down

Tags: html, css, multi-select, aurelia-templating

i have multiple multi select drop downs on a page,for example

i have a drop down that lists the months as follows

[image]

html

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l3">

<select multiple md-select value.bind="selectedMonth">
    <option value="" disabled>Month</option>
    <option repeat.for="month of months" value.bind="month">${month</option>
</select>
                    
</div>
```

so when the user is done selecting the items and the items is too long to display in the width of the box it starts to get cut off as follows.

[image]

i cant change the column size of the div because i need it to be that column width.
is there a way i can get it to display on the next line  like

[image]

or even as follows

[image]

Comment: Removing `white-space: nowrap` from `.md-select-value>span:not(.md-select-icon)` appears to do the trick (tested with the examples from https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select)

Comment: i tried this and its not working (i am using aurelia https://aurelia-ui-toolkits.github.io/demo-materialize/#/samples/select/multiple)

Comment: That appears to be using a single text input field to display the list of choices. I don't know of any trivial way to make that display across multiple lines.